# git checkout with changes from one branch to another

Tags: git

I am on `branchX`. I make some changes in my working directory. They all get reflected in "Changes not staged for commit".
Now I do `git checkout branchY`. Sometimes I get the changes getting moved into "Changes not staged for commit" of the branchY like :

```
M <some file1 path>
M <some file2 path>
```

and sometimes git gives me this message - `Please commit your changes or stash them before you switch branches.`

How does git decide it when to reflect the changes and when to abort ?
Should not git never move "Changes not staged for commit" changes of one branch into other if I checkout without committing them ?

Comment: Although there's already an accepted answer, I thought I should link this to the other question...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second message you're quoting (`Please commit your changes or stash them before you switch branches.`) occurs when moving your pending changes would create conflicts on the to-be-checked-out branch.

When no conflicts are detected, the working tree is first updated regarding the commit HEAD is now pointing to, *then* your pending changes are replayed above and you're ready to add more changes or commit right away.

And as a sidenote, it's widely considered a good practice to always return to a clean state before checking another branch out. Committing on the branch* or stashing changes are probably the most common ways to achieve this.

(* since this commit is only local for now, you'll have the opportunity to amend it or drop it entirely when you'll return to this branch.)

Answer (score 2):

The relevant documentation `man git-checkout` says:

> `git checkout <branch>`
>
> To prepare for working on `<branch>`, switch to it by updating the index and the files in the working tree, and by pointing `HEAD` at the branch. Local modifications to the files in the working tree are kept, so that they can be committed to the `<branch>`.

However, if the changes you made in the working directory overlap with changes introduced in the `<branch>`, you have a conflict. This is similar to merge conflicts, and thus the `checkout` is aborted.

You can use the `-m` (or `--merge`) flag to proceed with the `checkout` anyways, but you have to resolve the conflicts, as you would do while merging.